# Data Compression Model

Tags: python, encoding, compression

I am working on an exercise where we are to model Data Compression via a list. Say we were given a list: `[4,4,4,4,4,4,2,9,9,9,9,9,5,5,4,4]`
We should apply Run-length encoding, and get a new list of `[4,6,2,1,9,5,5,2,4,2]` where it shows how many 4's (6) 2's(1) 9's (5) 5's (2), etc.. jointly next to the integer.

So far I have the following code, however I am hitting a semantic error, and not sure how to fix it:

```
  def string_compression(List):
      newlist=[]
      counter=0
      x=0
      for elm in List:
          prev_item= List[x-1]
          current_item=List[x]
          if prev_item == current_item:
              counter+=1
          else:
              newlist+=[current_item]+[counter]
              counter=0
```

P.S I am still a beginner, so I apologize if it is a 'dumb' question! I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Missing indentation after `if elem == newlist[i2]:` and you define `counter` but then use undefined `total`, have you even bothered reading the error message?

Comment: @JulienBernu Thanks Julien. Have you even bothered reading my question? I didn't say syntax error.

Comment: Some thoughts: Try to use more descriptive names than "x", "index", "i", "i2", "counter". (These are so nonsensical you haven't noticed that some of them serve no purpose.) There is no point in testing whether a list element is a member of that list. (When will `List[index] in List` *not* be true?) You need only one loop. Solving this by hand, on paper, away from the computer, could be beneficial.

Comment: You may have not said it, but your code is full of it!

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks, but how can it only be one loop if we need to iterate the whole list, as well as per index

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really confusing with all these counters. What you need to do is implement the algorithm as it is defined. You need just a single index `i` which keeps track at what position of the list you are currently at and at each step compare the number to the previous number.

- if they are equal, then increment the counter
- if they are not equal then add the new pair of the tracked number with the count and reset the counter to 0 and set the new tracking number to the current number.

Comment: Wouldn't that be assuming the list are numerically in order however?

Comment: As I understand it, you need to encode it, not count the numbers.
For example [2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2] would result in [2,5,1,4,2,4].

Comment: def rlEncode (List):
           newlist=[]
           counter=0
           x=0
           for elm in List:
               prev_item= List[x-1]
               current_item=List[x]
               if prev_item == current_item:
                   counter+=1
               else:
                   newlist+=[current_item]+[counter]
                   counter=0
                
What do you think?

Comment: Sorry please disregard the comment and see edits on question. Please tell me what you think is missing

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but this is easier with an index-based loop:

```
def rle_encode(ls):
    # Special case: the empty list.
    if not ls:
        return []

    result = []

    # Count the first element in the list, whatever that is.
    count = 1
    # Loop from 1; we're considering the first element as counted already.
    # This is safe because we know that the list isn't empty.
    for i in range(1, len(ls)):
        if ls[i] == ls[i - 1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            # Store the last run.
            result.append(ls[i - 1])
            result.append(count)
            # Count the current number.
            count = 1
    # Add the last run since we didn't get a chance to in the loop.
    result.append(ls[-1])
    result.append(count)

    return result
```

Comment: thank you very much @molbdnilo, you're too helpful! I really appreciate the genuine clarity of your response!